# Chromecast Receiver App Query Parameters

Tags: chromecast

Why can't my Chromecast receiver app see passed query parameters? I'm using the example web app sender application @

http://googlecast.github.io/cast-chrome/

My receiver app is correctly launched on the Chromecast but the query parameters which I have provided do not appear to have been supplied.

Is this a problem with the sender application or are the supplied query params being lost somewhere?

Comment: I think one thing to note here is that logically it could be the sender application never sending the query params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you passing the query parameters? For query parameters to be accepted by the receiver, the receiver url should have an ending like: ...${POST_DATA} so as an example, the full url for a receiver should be like:

```
http://example.com/receiver/index.html?{POST_DATA}
```

If yours doesn't follow that, contact us so we can update your url.

Comment: I am unable to enter a URL of this form on the Chromecast whitelisting form. I am told that this is not a valid URL.

Comment: Also please explain how you are passing the query parameters

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm using the example web app sender. I'm entered a query param as "param=value" into the provided input field. I believe that this is then set on the request object, like this:
`
var request = new cast.LaunchRequest($scope.appName, receiver);
if ($scope.launchParameters) {
   request.parameters = $scope.launchParameters;
}
$scope.castApi.launch(request, resultCallback);
`

Comment: As per your suggestion I sent an email to chromecast-updates@google.com (I tried chromecasts-update@google.com but this was unreachable).

Comment: I have this working now after someone at Google modified by registered URLs internally to have the ?{POST_DATA} suffix. It would be good if validation on the whitelisting form was relaxed to permit this.